# How do I go through some numbers and pick the smallest number from them using a for loop inside an if statement?

Tags: java

How do I go through some numbers and pick the smallest number from them using a for loop inside an if statement?

```
for ( int i = 0; i < num; i++ )
{
    int small;
    if( num[i] == small )
    {
        a = small;
    }
}
```

I started with this I got the for loop but for the if statement not sure? I want to say if this number is the smallest get it.

Comment: Think about how you'd do it with just paper and pencil.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way.

```
public int smallestNumber(int[] numbers)
{
    int small = numbers[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < numbers.length;i++)
    {
        if(numbers[i]<small)
           small = numbers[i];
    }
return small;
}
```

Comment: `i < numbers.length-1`?

Comment: @ZongZhengLi Lol woops indeed :P

Answer (score 1):

```
int min = num[0];
for ( int i=1; i<num.length; i++)
{
    if( num[i] < min  )
    {
     min = num[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: You could start with `i = 1`.